# divs won't horizontally align in CSS

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

So I am having trouble aligning 3 divs that are circles on my page.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="large-9 push-2 columns">


    <div class="green"></div>
    <a href="#">Donnez</a>


</div>



<div class="row">
<div class="large-9 push-4 columns">

<div class="cyan"></div>
<a href="#">Recevez</a>


</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="large-9 push-6 columns">

<div class="orange"></div>
<a href="#">Statistique</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS :

```
.green, .cyan, .orange  {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px; 
    position: relative;
    float: left;

}
.green  {
background: #40b564;


}
.cyan   {
background: #61cfcc;

}

.orange {
background: #f8765c;

}
```

Here is what it looks like :

http://4.ii.gl/V0DOyL.png

I basically want the 3 circles (3 divs) to be aligned properly horizontally. Now I have tried display : inline-block; and other things but nothing seems to work. I don't know if this has anything to do with the fondation framework ? I have been trying to figure this out for hours now, any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: As @Dawood said in his answer you need to place all the columns in one row, you dont have to wrap each column with row. HERE IS THE DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/TjuH8/1/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have them in seperate `class="rows"` that is why they are in seperate lines.
You have to place them in one Row.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="large-4 columns">


    <div class="green"></div>
    <a href="#">Donnez</a>


</div>

<div class="large-4 columns">


    <div class="green"></div>
    <a href="#">Donnez</a>


</div>

<div class="large-4 columns">


    <div class="green"></div>
    <a href="#">Donnez</a>


</div>

</div>
```

Try this in your code, upload a new snapshot, I will see if I can help anymore.

Another Mistake I noticed is that (Not Related to your current layout):

```
<div class="large-9 push-6 columns">

<div class="orange"></div>
<a href="#">Statistique</a>
</div>
```

You are doing `large-9 push-6`, the total should not be more than 12. In you case it is 9+6=15, it should be like `large-9 push-3, large-8 push-4 or large-6 push-6` so that total is always 12

Comment: Thank you so much Dawood! Without that solution I would have encountered so many other problems in the future!

http://1.ii.gl/5Qv0_s.png
:D